# how to remove some words in php

Tags: php

I want to remove all the prepositions(in, at, on...), definite articles(a, an ,the...) and be verbs(is, are, was...) from a article. Is there a short way that php can do that?

```
$article= "the cup is on the table";// I want get an echo like "cup table"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php), create an array with the words you want gone and use `str_ireplace($prepArr,'',$str);`

Comment: this will also remove the letters from a string if a word contains letter for example removing for from a word Informatik

Answer (score 10):

The key thing is to ensure you only replace whole words (e.g. not the "the" in "there"), for which you can use `\b` in PCRE:

```
$words = array('in', 'at', 'on', 'etc..');
$pattern = '/\b(?:' . join('|', $words) . ')\b/i';
$article = preg_replace($pattern, '', $article);
```

Caveat 1: If you have a very large number of words to remove, you may hit the maximum pattern size, in which case you can construct the pattern for each one and pass an array of patterns to `preg_replace`.

Caveat 2: If the words you want to remove can contain characters of significance to PCRE, then you should call preg_quote($word, '/') to make them safe for the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace(Array(' in ', ' at ', ' on ', ' a ', ' an ', ' the '), '', $article);
```

Edit: better, using preg_replace:

```
$article = 'The cup is on the table.The theble aon is';
echo "<br/>". ($article = preg_replace("/(\W|^)(is|on|a|the)(\W|$)/i", ' ', $article));
echo "<br/>". ($article = preg_replace("/(\W|^)(is|on|a|the)(\W|$)/i", ' ', $article));
```

Not sure why you have to call the `preg_replace` twice though..

---

Seems like @Lacking Beers has the answer.

Comment: changed the :graph: to \W :) see http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php for details

Comment: You have to call it twice here because you're swallowing a character with the `\W`. If you had four words in a row instead of three, you'd need to call it three times. You can stop it swallowing characters by using lookbehind/lookahead assertions: `/(?<=\W|^)(is|on|a|the)(?=\W|$)/i` - at which point you might as well just use `\b` as in my answer.

Comment: I'd rather see `\b` implemented in these patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, simply call a str_ireplace()

```
$banned = array(' a ', ' an ', ' the '); //add more words as you want. KEEP THE SPACE around the word
$article = 'The cup is on the table';
$clear   = str_ireplace($banned, ' ', $article); //replaced with a space for now. put something else if you want
```

$clear will now be $article sans the banned words

**EDIT**
Added a comment to keep the spaces around the words

Comment: -1 this way, it will remove all 'a' characters from the string;)

Comment: ... and you'll get `  cup is on   t ble`.

Comment: wrong: $`article = 'The cup is on.The table is';` it wont work for this case

Comment: hmmm, and the same for '.On this day...'. This really only checks for words in the middle. Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

Comment: If you're doing it using str_replace(), then wrap $article in spaces as well - eg. $clear = str_ireplace($banned, ' ', ' '.$article.' '); but this won't help if there are punctuation marks in the article. Preg_replace, with \b word boundaries in the regexp is a lot cleaner

Comment: would that take into account all punctuation marks that might come into contact with the word? Really should sit down with cup of coffee and some regex :(

Comment: @JohnP - \b will work with pretty much every likely punctuation mark, though you may need the unicode switch if you encounter ¿ in a sentence, Lacking Ideas has answered this question with a regexp using \b

Answer (score 2):

```
echo str_replace(array(' the ', ' is ', ' on ', ' a '), ' ', $article);
```

Comment: -1 this way, it will remove all 'a' characters from the string;)

Comment: That was a clbuttic mistake :)

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx

Comment: No. This is working well
e.g "this is a demo and just checking"
Result: "this demo and just checking"

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful solution, try below code or you can add your words in $commonWords array.

```
function removeCommonWords($input){

    $commonWords = array('a','able','about','above','abroad','according','accordingly','across','actually','adj','after','afterwards','again','against','ago','ahead','ain\'t','all','allow','allows','almost','alone','along','alongside','already','also','although','always','am','amid','amidst','among','amongst','an','and','another','any','anybody','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway','anyways','anywhere','apart','appear','appreciate','appropriate','are','aren\'t','around','as','a\'s','aside','ask','asking','associated','at','available','away','awfully','b','back','backward','backwards','be','became','because','become','becomes','becoming','been','before','beforehand','begin','behind','being','believe','below','beside','besides','best','better','between','beyond','both','brief','but','by','c','came','can','cannot','cant','can\'t','caption','cause','causes','certain','certainly','changes','clearly','c\'mon','co','co.','com','come','comes','concerning','consequently','consider','considering','contain','containing','contains','corresponding','could','couldn\'t','course','c\'s','currently','d','dare','daren\'t','definitely','described','despite','did','didn\'t','different','directly','do','does','doesn\'t','doing','done','don\'t','down','downwards','during','e','each','edu','eg','eight','eighty','either','else','elsewhere','end','ending','enough','entirely','especially','et','etc','even','ever','evermore','every','everybody','everyone','everything','everywhere','ex','exactly','example','except','f','fairly','far','farther','few','fewer','fifth','first','five','followed','following','follows','for','forever','former','formerly','forth','forward','found','four','from','further','furthermore','g','get','gets','getting','given','gives','go','goes','going','gone','got','gotten','greetings','h','had','hadn\'t','half','happens','hardly','has','hasn\'t','have','haven\'t','having','he','he\'d','he\'ll','hello','help','hence','her','here','hereafter','hereby','herein','here\'s','hereupon','hers','herself','he\'s','hi','him','himself','his','hither','hopefully','how','howbeit','however','hundred','i','i\'d','ie','if','ignored','i\'ll','i\'m','immediate','in','inasmuch','inc','inc.','indeed','indicate','indicated','indicates','inner','inside','insofar','instead','into','inward','is','isn\'t','it','it\'d','it\'ll','its','it\'s','itself','i\'ve','j','just','k','keep','keeps','kept','know','known','knows','l','last','lately','later','latter','latterly','least','less','lest','let','let\'s','like','liked','likely','likewise','little','look','looking','looks','low','lower','ltd','m','made','mainly','make','makes','many','may','maybe','mayn\'t','me','mean','meantime','meanwhile','merely','might','mightn\'t','mine','minus','miss','more','moreover','most','mostly','mr','mrs','much','must','mustn\'t','my','myself','n','name','namely','nd','near','nearly','necessary','need','needn\'t','needs','neither','never','neverf','neverless','nevertheless','new','next','nine','ninety','no','nobody','non','none','nonetheless','noone','no-one','nor','normally','not','nothing','notwithstanding','novel','now','nowhere','o','obviously','of','off','often','oh','ok','okay','old','on','once','one','ones','one\'s','only','onto','opposite','or','other','others','otherwise','ought','oughtn\'t','our','ours','ourselves','out','outside','over','overall','own','p','particular','particularly','past','per','perhaps','placed','please','plus','possible','presumably','probably','provided','provides','q','que','quite','qv','r','rather','rd','re','really','reasonably','recent','recently','regarding','regardless','regards','relatively','respectively','right','round','s','said','same','saw','say','saying','says','second','secondly','see','seeing','seem','seemed','seeming','seems','seen','self','selves','sensible','sent','serious','seriously','seven','several','shall','shan\'t','she','she\'d','she\'ll','she\'s','should','shouldn\'t','since','six','so','some','somebody','someday','somehow','someone','something','sometime','sometimes','somewhat','somewhere','soon','sorry','specified','specify','specifying','still','sub','such','sup','sure','t','take','taken','taking','tell','tends','th','than','thank','thanks','thanx','that','that\'ll','thats','that\'s','that\'ve','the','their','theirs','them','themselves','then','thence','there','thereafter','thereby','there\'d','therefore','therein','there\'ll','there\'re','theres','there\'s','thereupon','there\'ve','these','they','they\'d','they\'ll','they\'re','they\'ve','thing','things','think','third','thirty','this','thorough','thoroughly','those','though','three','through','throughout','thru','thus','till','to','together','too','took','toward','towards','tried','tries','truly','try','trying','t\'s','twice','two','u','un','under','underneath','undoing','unfortunately','unless','unlike','unlikely','until','unto','up','upon','upwards','us','use','used','useful','uses','using','usually','v','value','various','versus','very','via','viz','vs','w','want','wants','was','wasn\'t','way','we','we\'d','welcome','well','we\'ll','went','were','we\'re','weren\'t','we\'ve','what','whatever','what\'ll','what\'s','what\'ve','when','whence','whenever','where','whereafter','whereas','whereby','wherein','where\'s','whereupon','wherever','whether','which','whichever','while','whilst','whither','who','who\'d','whoever','whole','who\'ll','whom','whomever','who\'s','whose','why','will','willing','wish','with','within','without','wonder','won\'t','would','wouldn\'t','x','y','yes','yet','you','you\'d','you\'ll','your','you\'re','yours','yourself','yourselves','you\'ve','z','zero');

    return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);
}
```